# android studio arctic fox can not start

Tags: android

By running studio.bat
D:\Jet brains\Android Studio\bin>studio.bat
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /absolute/path/to/multi-markdown-agent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Android Studio --> Settings --> Appearance & Behavior --> System Settings --> Android SDK --> SDK Tools
2. Then Download Command line tools
3. Invalidate caches and Restart.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer，Run CMD to run studio. bat and see an error message,Because the lower version of Studio installation can be run, I downloaded the lower version and upgraded the version according to your method, but there is no solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your internet is on and open Android Studio and it will install necessary requirements by it self. And Got **Tools->Sdk Manager** and install necessary libraries and SDK

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer，Run CMD to run studio. bat and see an error message,Because the lower version of Studio installation can be run, I downloaded the lower version and upgraded the version according to your method,And then upgrade the version，But there is no solution

Comment: uninstall android studio, remove all files of android studio then download latest version of android studio and install it

Comment: That has been done，The result was a headache，And then there was the question，
D:\Jet brains\Android Studio\bin>studio.bat
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /absolute/path/to/multi-markdown-agent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument